# Attach handler to an event: parameters

Tags: vb.net

I have the following piece of code:

```
AddHandler sharepoint.UploadCompleted, AddressOf UploadEmailCompleted
```

I require it to work like so:

```
AddHandler sharepoint.UploadCompleted, AddressOf UploadEmailCompleted(message)
```

I fully appreciate this isn't possible, and after a little research, I think using a delegate may be the way forward. However I'm struggling to implement a solution that works.

Am I on the right track, or is what I'm attempting not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `message` intended to be? Is it the message that was sent, or an error message? If sharepoint.UploadedCompleted returns EventArgs, you can access these within your callback function. For example I have the following code for loading an email template within a service:

```
Public Function LoadEmailTemplate(ByVal template As String)

    Dim path As String = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "EmailTemplates\" + template

    Return (File.ReadAllText(path))

End Function
```

Then within my client app, I just do:

```
Private Sub loadEmailTemplate_completed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MainServiceReference.LoadEmailTemplateCompletedEventArgs)

    Dim body As String = e.Result
    body = body.Replace("{CHEMICAL}", chemApp.Chemical.tradeName)
    body = body.Replace("{REQUESTEDBY}", chemApp.requestedBy)
    body = body.Replace("{FACILITY}", chemApp.facilityPath)
    body = body.Replace("{ID}", chemApp.ID)



    clientMain.SendMailAsync(toAddress, fromAddress, subject, body)

End Sub
```

I can then access the return value via the `LoadEmailTemplateCompletedEventArgs`. Can you do something similar with sharepoint.uploadcompleted? i.e configure it to return a value, then access it via EventArgs?

Oh, for reference, the event handler is just:

```
AddHandler clientMain.LoadEmailTemplateCompleted, AddressOf loadEmailTemplate_completed
```